# Installing MacPorts on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I installed MacPorts from the DMG package at http://www.macports.org/install.php

After installing it I tried to use it and get this:

```
dlopen(/opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/macports1.0/MacPorts.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/macports1.0/MacPorts.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    while executing
"load /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/macports1.0/MacPorts.dylib"
    ("package ifneeded macports 1.0" script)
    invoked from within
"package require macports"
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 39)
```

I tried removing /opt/local/share/macports and /opt/local/bin/port and reinstalling, but it did not help.

**Update:**

I tried a complete removal by doing

```
%% sudo rm -rf \
    /opt/local \
    /Applications/DarwinPorts \
    /Applications/MacPorts \
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
    /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
    /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
    /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
    ~/.macports
```

And then installing MacPorts-1.9.2-10.6-SnowLeopard.dmg but still I get same error.

Comment: If you don't specifically need MacPorts you can try [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/) which is a more up-to-date replacement with easier installation and usage. Just run `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/raw/323731/install_homebrew.rb)"`

Comment: Thanks slhck, I went with MacPorts because it was one of the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868185/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-osx-10-5-8-for-google-app-engine

Comment: @user16145 Ok! Btw you can put your working solution as an answer to this question and accept it in two days.

Comment: We'd appreciate if you added an answer to the question as @slhck suggests, otherwise; it'll get automatically bumped to the front page, as the system thinks it's unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it from source.

```
tar xjvf MacPorts-1.9.2.tar.bz2
cd MacPorts-1.9.2
./configure && make && sudo make install
sudo port -v selfupdate
```