# "sudo: port: command not found" after installing MacPorts on Snow leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, path, macports

I have attempted to install MacPorts in order to upgrade my Rails version so that I can work my way through Agile Web Development with Rails, PragProg (4th, 2011). I have followed the directions in the book, as well as on the [MacPorts  web site](http://www.macports.org/install.php), to perform the install from disk image. It appeared to install correctly, however, running port commands afterwards returned "port: command not found".

I searched Stack Exchange and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/275912/installing-macports-on-snow-leopard), so I attempted to install from the command line using "tar xjvf MacPorts-1.9.2.tar.bz2". Again, the install seems to work. I receive the confirmation that MacPorts installed successfully, but I still receive "sudo: port: command not found" error on trying to selfupdate MacPorts (via "sudo port -v selfupdate").

I think that my error lies in not having the correct path set. I followed the advice in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard), namely, adding a path (/opt/local) in paths.d, but I still get the error.

If it matters, terminal is set to open shells with default login shell (/usr/bin/login). Should I change this to /bin/bash?

So, is this a MacPorts issue, a $PATH issue, or a StupidUser issue?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It *is* probably a PATH issue.

By default `port` is installed the directory `/opt/local/bin`. Add the path 'opt/local/bin' as an extra line to the plain text file `/etc/paths` and you should be good.

Answer (score 54):

You can also add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

This will add `/opt/local/bin` to the executable path and make your `port` command available to the shell.

Comment: I created .bash_profile and added export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info lines...but still it's giving me same problem..i am using OS version 10.8.3 .any suggestion?

Comment: I'll just add that you have to restart your computer.

Comment: @Baldráni no need to restart. Try - `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 8):

open a terminal, then write:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

write your password

then copy and paste in to the bottom:

```
/opt/local/bin
```

save the file:

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and then <kbd>y</kbd>

Restart the computer.

Answer (score 3):

this is working for me:

first open this file with nano

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

if it doesnt exist create it manually or with

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

add this line to the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

now reload .bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, I was running into the same issue and I ended up adding the below line to my .bash_profile file (I am on Ventura macOS)

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169738)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].